# I am getting different results when running my Haskell code interactively using ghci and when loading it as a module

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci, exponential

Code loaded from .hs file:

```
modPow :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
modPow a k m = (a^2 `mod` m)^(k `div` 2)
```

code entered interactively:

```
(13481503^2 `mod` 46340)^(11237126 `div` 2)
```

i.e `a = 13481503`, `k = 11237126`, `m = 46340`

The former returns a completely different number when called in ghci with the same values i.e `modPow 13481503 11237126 46340`

Answer (score 4):

Look at the type of the expression you use:

```
> :t (13481503^2 `mod` 46340)^(11237126 `div` 2)
(13481503^2 `mod` 46340)^(11237126 `div` 2) :: Integral a => a
```

`ghci` defaults to `Integer` when forced to evaluate a value of type `Integral a => a` (as happens with the implicit call to `show` by the interactive interpreter), whereas your function returns an `Int`.

Answer (score 3):

You define `modPow` as `Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`, i.e. it accepts and returns `Int`s (64-bit integers), therefore all operations are modulo 64 bits.

When you execute the expression manually, GHCI upcasts your numbers to `Integer` (which is unlimited in size), producing the correct output.

Comment: is there a way to do the same thing without changing the signature ? thanks

Comment: No, if the return type is limited in size (64-bits), you can't return the unlimited `Integer` type..

Answer (score 1):

You're raising something to the power of 5,618,563. That's an *enormous* number. The biggest number you can represent with `Int` (assuming it's a signed 64 bit integer) is `(2 ^ 63) - 1`. Since 5,618,563 > 63, anything raised to the power of five million can't fit in an `Int` (unless the "anything" is 1, 0, or -1). So `modPow :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int` will be overflowing

Entering the same operations *without* a type signature will default to `Integer`, which is not limited to 64 bits the way `Int`. So the calculation will not overflow and will give the true result. That happens whether you did it in a module or in GHCi; you've misdiagnosed what the significant difference between your two tests was.